# How to create a virtual printer using Node.js

Tags: node.js, printers, ipp-protocol

I try to create virtual printer like this
[image]

I tried to use [ipp-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipp-printer)  module  create virtual printer but I can't add my printer

```
var fs = require('fs') 

var Printer = require('ipp-printer')

var printer = new Printer({name:"my-printer", port:8081})
printer.on('job', function (job) {
  console.log('[job %d] Printing document: %s', job.id, job.name)
  var filename = 'job-' + job.id + '.ps' // .ps = PostScript
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(filename)
  job.on('end', function () {
    console.log('[job %d] Document saved as %s', job.id, filename)
  })

  job.pipe(file)
})
```

I'can't see my-printer name in add printer screen

[image]